# Cannot close Dialog on Python PyQt4

Tags: python, model-view-controller, dialog, pyqt4, exit

My program has a MainWindow which contains my inventory system. I have added a Dialog window which pop-ups when I clicked "Add Item". I am able to successfully open the Dialog window but I can't seem to close it.

When the user tries to close the Dialog Window, it will display a messagebox asking if the user really wants to close the window. Currently, I'm using ***self.close()***. It just closes the MessageBox I've made to prevent accidental exit and doesn't close the Dialog window unless you end it using the IDE or task manager.

Here's my code snippets:

Main.py

```
class Main(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.db = Database()
        self.model = Model(self)
        self.ui = MainWindow_ui()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.window = Ui_Dialog()

        self.ui.addItem.clicked.connect(lambda : self.start_Form())

    def start_Form(self):
        window = QtGui.QDialog()
        self.window.setupUi(window)
        self.window.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Main()
    window.showMaximized()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

AddItem.py (contains the Dialog Window code)

```
def getNumber():
    conn = sqlite3.connect('inventory.db')
    c = conn.cursor()
    c.execute('SELECT seq FROM sqlite_sequence')
    itemNumber = c.fetchone()[0]
    return int(itemNumber) + 1

class Ui_Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.setupUi(self)

    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("Dialog"))
        Dialog.resize(413, 382)

        self.buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(Dialog)
        self.buttonBox.setStandardButtons(
            QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Reset)
        self.buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        self.buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):    
        self.itemCode.setText(str(getNumber()))

    def accept(self):
        row = self.mapper.currentIndex()
        self.mapper.submit()
        self.main.model.insertRow(row)
        self.mapper.setCurrentIndex(row)

        self.close()

    def reject(self):
        ret = QtGui.QMessageBox.question(None, 'Close request', 'Are you sure you want to quit?',
                                         QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes | QtGui.QMessageBox.No)
        if ret == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            self.close()
        else:
            pass
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `accept()` and `reject()` methods effectively create an infinite loop, because calling `close()` will, in turn, just call those methods again. When overriding virtual methods, you should call the base-class implementation using `super`:

```
class Ui_Dialog(QtGui.QDialog):
    ...

    def accept(self):
        ...
        super(Ui_Dialog, self).accept()  

    def reject(self):
        ...
        if ret == QtGui.QMessageBox.Yes:
            super(Ui_Dialog, self).reject()
```

Comment: In addition, do you know how to insert data in a new row into the QSqlRelationalTableModel using the form in the Ui_Dialog?

Comment: @lloydyu24. Please ask a new question.